# fullCalendar / ASP.Net / jQuery 1.5

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to figure out how to use the jquery fullCalendar control. I can't get past the very first line which simply attaches a calendar to a "div". Straight from the fullCalendar home page. I'm pretty sure I have jQuery referenced correctly in my master page since I can get other simple controls to work. What am I missing? Is fullCalendar NOT compatible with ASP.Net MVC 2 and jQuery 1.5?

Pretty simple code. The error I get is: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [#calendar]". Here's the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src="../../Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[#calendar]').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: false,
            events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: false,
            events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note the lack of `[]`.  In jQuery a div's ID is referenced by # only.  See the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for more details.